# I can't uninstall any module after I uninstalled deprecated modules

Tags: drush

I have Drupal 9.5 installed and running. I have uninstalled 3 deprecated modules (*Aggregator*, *Color*, and *RDF*). After that, I can't uninstall any module using the user interface. It gives the following error.

> LogicException: Missing bundle entity, entity type comment_type, entity id comment. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityType->getBundleConfigDependency() (line 885 of web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityType.php).

This error is linked to the *Field Layout* core module. The error shows when I try to uninstall that module. Rather showing the confirmation, it shows the error. Then, whatever module I try to uninstall, it shows the same error.

So I re-installed the *RDF* module. After some time (I don't know what I did), I can see the uninstall confirmation page for modules. When I try to uninstall the *Field Layout* module, it shows the error, which is shown also for other modules.

The site is working okay, but uninstalling modules is not possible. I can uninstall modules using Drush. I ran `drush cr` and `drush updb`, but that error is still shown.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was reported as a major Drupal Core bug. This can’t be both a question and a bug. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3357525

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to reproduce this uninstalling and installing of unrelated modules.

The error message itself says the comment type `comment` is missing. This is part of the standard profile and could be easily recreated, either in UI */admin/structure/comment* or by importing:

*web/core/profiles/standard/config/install/comment.type.comment.yml*

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: comment
label: 'Default comments'
target_entity_type_id: node
description: 'Allows commenting on content'
```

Goto */admin/config/development/configuration/single/import*, select the configuration type "Comment type" and paste the configuration.